# Kotlin Annotation not present at Runtime

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-reflect

I'm trying to use Kotlin Reflection to generate JFrames from Classes with their members.
I have created a couple Annotations, some of them are present at runtime and some are not.

Component Annotation:

```
@Target(AnnotationTarget.FIELD, AnnotationTarget.PROPERTY)
@Retention(AnnotationRetention.RUNTIME)
annotation class Component(val constraints: String = "")
```

IsEnabled Annotation:

```
@Target(AnnotationTarget.FIELD, AnnotationTarget.PROPERTY)
@Retention(AnnotationRetention.RUNTIME)
annotation class IsEnabled(val value: Boolean = true)
```

I'm using both of the Annotations like this:

```
class DisabledTest {
    @Component
    @IsEnabled(false)
    val btn = JButton("Should be Disabled")
}
```

If I run the following code:

```
DisabledTest::class.declaredMembers.forEach {
    println(it.name + ": " + it.annotations.map { a -> a.annotationClass.simpleName })
}
```

The only output I get is this:
`btn: [Component]`

What is happening to the `@IsEnabled` Annotation because the Retention is set to `AnnotationRetention.RUNTIME`?

Answer (score 0):

I reran the code multiple times again after doing some changes to the `class DisabledTest`, which don't have to do anything with the Annotations, and it just worked.

I have no idea why it is present at runtime now.

Comment: Possibly an issue of previous runs using already built code and not properly rebuilding. Possibly the file wasn't actually saved when rebuilding.